# How do I create an excel formula to pick out differences in 2 cell values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, cells

I have a column of company names (column A), a column of the 2014 revenue (column B) and a row of the 2015 revenue (column C).

I want to somehow pick out which companies had zero revenue in 2014 and then increased it in 2015 (increase can be anything greater than 0). I also want to pick out the reverse: companies which had revenue in 2014 but then went down to zero in 2015.

How do I do this? Thank you.

Comment: Have you given any thought to how you would approach this?  Is there a particular aspect that's causing you difficulty?  Have you tried anything and run into a problem?  How do you want to indicate a positive or negative change (format a cell, display a flag or the amount of change, Pluses and minuses in different columns)?  Super User isn't a programming service to do your work for you, but we can help you solve a specific problem if you get stuck.  Please put in a few minutes yourself to clearly define the requirement, and research solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a nested "IF" - where you put a second "IF" statement inside the "value_if_true" parameter of the first IF statement.

E.g.

To test if values in column B are 0 and values in column C are greater than zero:

=IF(B2=0,IF(C2>0,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)

To test if values in column B are non-zero and values in column C are zero:

=IF(B2<>0,IF(C2=0,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)

Answer (score 0):

I feel this is should be a comment but I don't have that much reputation.

If you just want some sort of status indicator, let's say you have the following:

```
Company -> A1
Rev.2014 -> B1
Rev.2015 -> C1
Status -> D1
```

Add the following formula in D2:

```
=IF((C2-B2)>0, "PROFIT", "LOSS")
```

Then expand it to all the subsequent cells and thus this column would show whether the company increased its PROFIT or incurred a LOSS.

UPDATE:
After Ben McEvoy's comment,
The formula should be:

```
=IF(B2=0,IF(C2>0,"PROFIT", "LOSS"),IF(C2=0,IF(B2>0,"LOSS","PROFIT"),"UKNOWN"))
```

The "UNKNOWN" is when neither B2 or C2 are equal to zero.

Comment: This will only show an increase or decrease in revenue - not whether either value was 0, which is what the original question asks for.